# Odoo How to set user access group for Create Invoice Button?

Tags: python, python-2.7, odoo, odoo-10

I try to assign user access group on Create Invoice Button. However it doesn't work and show these following error msg.

```
ParseError: "Error while validating constraint

Element '<xpath expr="//button[@name='239'][0]">' cannot be located in parent view

Error context:
View `sale.order.invoice`
[view_id: 547, xml_id: n/a, model: sale.order, parent_id: 509]
None" while parsing /mnt/extra-addons/self-addons/wongnai_flow/views/invoices/create_invoice.xml:3, near
<record model="ir.ui.view">
  <field name="name">sale.order.invoice</field>
  <field name="model">sale.order</field>
  <field name="inherit_id" ref="sale.view_order_form"/>
  <field name="arch" type="xml">
    <xpath expr="//button[@name='%(sale.action_view_sale_advance_payment_inv)d'][0]" position="replace">
      <button name="%(sale.action_view_sale_advance_payment_inv)d" string="Create Invoice" type="action" class="btn-primary" attrs="{'invisible': [('invoice_status', '!=', 'to invoice')]}" groups="wongnai_flow.group_lead"/>
    </xpath>
  </field>
</record>
```

I don't know what happen. I think my code is already correct.

Do you have any suggestion??

```
<record model="ir.ui.view">
  <field name="name">sale.order.invoice</field>
  <field name="model">sale.order</field>
  <field name="inherit_id" ref="sale.view_order_form"/>
  <field name="arch" type="xml">
    <xpath expr="//button[@name='%(sale.action_view_sale_advance_payment_inv)d'][0]" position="replace">
      <button name="%(sale.action_view_sale_advance_payment_inv)d" string="Create Invoice"
                    type="action" class="btn-primary"
                    attrs="{'invisible': [('invoice_status', '!=', 'to invoice')]}"
                    groups="wongnai_flow.group_lead"/>
    </xpath>
  </field>
</record>
<record model="ir.ui.view">
  <field name="name">sale.order.invoice</field>
  <field name="model">sale.order</field>
  <field name="inherit_id" ref="sale.view_order_form"/>
  <field name="arch" type="xml">
    <xpath expr="//button[@name='%(sale.action_view_sale_advance_payment_inv)d'][1]" position="replace">
      <button name="%(sale.action_view_sale_advance_payment_inv)d" string="Create Invoice"
                    type="action" context="{'default_advance_payment_method': 'percentage'}"
                    attrs="{'invisible': ['|',('invoice_status', '!=', 'no'), ('state', '!=', 'sale')]}"
                    groups="wongnai_flow.group_lead"/>
    </xpath>
  </field>
</record>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your Xpath is not seem be to correct. Please try the following

```
<xpath expr="//button[@name='%(action_view_sale_advance_payment_inv)d']" position="attributes">
    <attribute name="groups">wongnai_flow.group_lead</attribute>
</xpath>
```

Comment: @sfx Please Help : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49955908/not-able-to-add-the-group-sale-manger-to-action-invoice-cancel-button