# Not able to add the group sale_manger to action_invoice_cancel button

Tags: xml, odoo, odoo-10, odoo-view

I want to add sale_manager group to the `action_invoice_cancel` (Invoice Cancel) button in the `customer invoice` . My aim is to see that button only for the users in the sale_manager. 
I tried like this :

> Code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<odoo>
    <record id="orchid_invoice_cancel_request_inherit" model="ir.ui.view">
        <field name="name">invoice_cancel_request</field>
        <field name="model">account.invoice</field>
        <field name="inherit_id" ref="account.invoice_form"/>
        <field name="arch" type="xml">
             <button name="action_invoice_cancel" position="after">
                <button string="Cancel Request" type="object" name="cancel_request" attrs="{'invisible':[('state','not in',('open','paid'))]}"/>
             </button>
             <field name = "move_id" position="after">
                <field name = "od_cancel_reason" />
             </field>

             <button name="action_invoice_cancel" position="replace">
                <button name="action_invoice_cancel" type="object" states="draft,proforma2,open" string="Cancel Invoice" groups="base.group_no_one,sales_team.group_sale_manager"/>
             </button>

        </field>
    </record>
</odoo>
```

But its not working. What to do ?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: are you sure that you have replaced the button and why didn't you just set the attribute groups?!!

Comment: Actually the button cannot be replaced.I don't know why?How can I set the attribute groups?  @Cherif

Comment: Can you also tell me how to do it using `xpath` ? @Cherif

Comment: And which is the group `base.group_no_one` ? 
I tried removing it but nothing happens . @Cherif

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The invoice form's *Cancel Invoice* button can certainly be modified (replaced or updated via `attributes`). Based on your question, it seems most likely that your module either does not load your view or maybe you did not re-upgrade your module.

As for your approach, I will show how to use `attributes` to change the `groups` of that button without needing to replace it entirely (as @Cherif suggested).

This will update one "attribute" of an existing element without needing to redefine the entire element. You should be able to change any one (or more) of the attributes for an element, however we just want to change `groups` in your case.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<odoo>
    <record id="orchid_invoice_cancel_request_inherit" model="ir.ui.view">
        <field name="name">invoice_cancel_request</field>
        <field name="model">account.invoice</field>
        <field name="inherit_id" ref="account.invoice_form"/>
        <field name="arch" type="xml">
             <button name="action_invoice_cancel" position="attributes">
                <attribute name="groups">sales_team.group_sale_manager"</attribute>
             </button>
        </field>
    </record>
</odoo>
```

[Views Documentation](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/10.0/reference/views.html#inheritance-specs)

Comment: Will check and revert @travisw . Currently I'm working on another project.
Thanks for the reply.